# Good pattern for expressjs rest APIs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, express

In order to organize my code I decided to create a methods folder and for each URL endpoint (website.com/billings for example) I store the endpoint name as a js file.

```
//expressJS configuration...
const billings = require('./methods/billings.js');

app.get('/billings', billings.get);
app.post('/billings', billings.post);
```

Then in `methods/billings.js`

Is there a better way? Or a convention?

```
get = async (req, res) => {
    //...
}
post = async (req, res) => {
    //...
}
module.exports.get = get;
module.exports.post = post;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways you can organize your code but i think that a very good way to do so is to use [express generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) that creates a skeleton with a good folder structure and provides you with an idea how to organize everything properly. MDN has a great  [express tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/skeleton_website) that should answer a lot of your questions. Here is a [github link](https://github.com/mdn/express-locallibrary-tutorial) of that tutorial were you can see how they organized code in their REST api. I hope this helps.